# Phonegap - Phonegap to Utils change

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

So I had an app running Phonegap 1.4.0 (don't ask), I decided to upgrade to 1.8.1, upon doing so the Phonegap global variable was no more, to be replaced with utils.

So I converted every occurance of:

```
var thisUUID = Phonegap.createUUID();
```

to:

```
var thisUUID = utils.createUUID();
```

only to be greeted with 'utils' is not defined reference error when running the application. So I opened up cordova-1.8.1.js and see that utils and utils.createUUID are indeed being defined globally, so I have no idea why when I try and call it I'm not generating a UUID, nor anything for that matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same requirement but I found the the utils is not exported as an external module so I used it the following way:

```
var utils = cordova.require('cordova/utils');
var myid = utils.createUUID();
```